# Getting Error ExceptioninInitializeError

Tags: android, android-ndk

When I create object of Epubreader I get this error. I am doing as follows

```
EpubReader epubReader = new EpubReader();
```

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8929521/exceptionininitializererror-in-android-app

Comment: I am getting nothing from that link

Comment: Ok check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3375810/exception-in-initializer-error

Comment: I dont use any static method or class..

Comment: Where do u write this code : EpubReader epubReader = new EpubReader();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may have to add some needed jar in libs.
take a look here :

[EPubReaderActivity eBook reading error ExceptionInInitializerError](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10244462/ebook-reading-error)